# How do I pass $_FILE and $_POST data into a form?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

So far this is what I know to be the way to pass the data from a post into the form.

```
$form->setData( $this->getRequest()->getPost() );
```

I thought that this might work

```
$form
    ->setData( $this->getRequest()->getPost() )
    ->setData( $this->getRequest()->getFiles() );
```

Which it does not. Looking through the framework source I confirmed that it shouldn't. So I was thinking about merging the file data into post data. Surely this cannot be the desired solution? It's not as if getPost() and getFiles() return easily mergeable arrays, they return Parameter objects.

**Please note this is Zend Framework 2 specific.**

Comment: It would be helpful to know what framework you are using as well. As standard `HTML/PHP` forms when you post a multipart/form-data form with a file input the `$_FILE` will work. Your code snipplet appears to be part of something outside of standalone PHP, either MVC, CMS, or maybe even a form handling class, but knowing what specifically may help overall answer this question.

Comment: @chris It was already tagged zend-framework2. Hope that helps.

Comment: valid point, far to often do I not pay attention to tags..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried `getFileInfo` knowing now or paying mind to the fact that your using Zend. Typically on a per file basis `$_FILE` is an array based on the information of the file being uploaded. Filename, extension, etc.. Zends `getFileInfo` outputs that information in a similar fashion. Though I haven't played with it in sometime, its worth looking into

Example concept (more for multiple file uploads I know, but works with one, good concept to leave in tact just incase you wanna add a second or more files down the road)

```
$uploads = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
$files  = $uploads->getFileInfo();

foreach($files as $file => $fileInfo) {
    if ($uploads->isUploaded($file)) {
        if ($uploads->isValid($file)) {
            if ($uploads->receive($file)) {
                $info = $uploads->getFileInfo($file);
                $tmp  = $info[$file]['tmp_name'];
                $data = file_get_contents($tmp);
                // here $tmp is the location of the uploaded file on the server
                // var_dump($info); to see all the fields you can use
            }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I am now trying to implement this. In ZF2 this is used something like this like this: use Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http as ZendFileTransferAdapterHttp; ....... $upload = new ZendFileTransferAdapterHttp();

Comment: ... however my solution is working in the controller and I would like to encapsulate it within the form object and input filter. It's not popular to say this at the moment by I want forms to be more tightly coupled to save time.

Answer (score 3):

After attempting to use Zend's file transfer adapter I went with a workaround in the controller. I think that the setData() in the form class should merge the items into the data instead of replacing them. (IMHO)

```
protected function getPostedData()
{
    if ( is_null($this->postedData) )
    {
        $this->postedData = array_merge(
            (array) $this->getRequest()->getPost(),
            (array) $this->getRequest()->getFiles()
        );
    }
    return $this->postedData;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using **array_merge**:

```
    $form    = $this->getForm('my_form');
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if($request->isPost())
    {

        $file    = $this->params()->fromFiles('name_of_file');
        $form->setData(array_merge(
            $request->getPost()->toArray(),
            array('arquivo' => $file['name'])
        ));

        if ($form->isValid()) {
        // now i can validate the form field
```

Answer (score 0):

I use variable variables like [this](http://www.onlineaspect.com/2009/05/31/how-to-use-variable-variables-in-php/) article explains to create variables and then echo them as the values for each form entry.

example:

```
// create array of GET/POST variables then convert each variable to a local variable
$fields = array_keys($_REQUEST);
foreach ($fields as $field) {
   $$field = $_REQUEST[$field];
}
```

Comment: Thanks Noel. A neat enough solution, however I was looking for something geared towards Zend Framework 2

Comment: I'd be careful using `$_REQUEST` its fine in development, but in production could be costly. More so if your not validating them well enough. Cause `$_REQUEST` is a global var, that can essentially be anything with the matching type, so I could pass a COOKIE even and have it run through that foreach as an example.

Comment: Sorry tomwrong I don't know anything about Zend but was hoping this might help, goodluck! You are absolutely right chris steps would have to be taken to validate the input here.

Comment: @Noel a minor point but $$ ? come one, it's sweet as. (hopefully not too patronising) :)